# Transparent pixel in SKMutableTexture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktexture

I am using a SKMutableTexture to render destructable ground in a game. For all intents and purposes, this works great, except for when I want to render a transparent pixel into a position in the MutableTexture where there is already a non-transparent pixel.

I have created a struct for RGBAColor like so:

```
struct RGBAColor {

    var r: UInt8
    var g: UInt8
    var b: UInt8
    var a: UInt8


    static var clear    = RGBAColor(r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0)
}
```

I then modify the SKMutableTexture like so:

```
self.texture.modifyPixelData({ (voidptr, len) in

            let bytes = voidptr!.assumingMemoryBound(to: RGBAColor.self)

            for (index, color) in self.modifiedPixels {
                bytes[index] = color
                self.pixels[index] = color
            }

        })
```

.. where "modifiedPixels" is a dictionary like [Int : RGBAColor] (in order not to update all pixels within the texture - only the modified ones.

It works as I intended when the color has an alpha (a) > 0 .. but not when it is 0 (it is like the pixel is rendered on top of the existing texture .. and not like you are modifying the actual pixel data).

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `SKMutableTexture` documentation,

> The color components you provide should have already been multiplied
>   by the alpha value.

Normally, if you wanted a color that is red with an alpha of 0.5, you would use RGBA components

```
(red:1.0, green:0.0, blue:0.0, alpha:0.5)
```

The equivalent for a *premultiplied-alpha* color is

```
(red:0.5, green:0.0, blue:0.0, alpha:0.5)
```

where the RGB components have been multiplied by the alpha value.

For your specific case, you can add an initializer to the `Color` structure to perform the multiplication. Here's one way implement that...

First, define an extension to scale a `UInt8` by a `Float` value by

```
extension UInt8 {
    func scaled(by value:Float) -> UInt8 {
        var scale = UInt(round(Float(self) * value))
        scale = Swift.min(scale, UInt(UInt8.max))
        return UInt8(scale)
    }
}
```

and then add an initializer that automatically multiples the components by the alpha value

```
struct Color {
    var red:UInt8
    var green:UInt8
    var blue:UInt8
    var alpha:UInt8

    init(red:UInt8,green:UInt8,blue:UInt8,alpha:UInt8) {
        let alphaScale = Float(alpha) / Float(UInt8.max)
        self.red = red.scaled(by: alphaScale)
        self.blue = blue.scaled(by: alphaScale)
        self.green = green.scaled(by: alphaScale)
        self.alpha = alpha
    }
}
```

You can then create a color that is red with alpha = 0.5 by

```
let color = Color(red:255, green:0, blue:0, alpha:127)
```

and a completely transparent color with

```
let color = Color(red:255, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0)
```

Comment: Thank you :) Completely missed the part about premultiplied alpha in the docs.